# Implementing equals/hashcode in specific case for checking if a list is subset of sublist

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, equals, hashcode

I know that I should implement `hashCode()` and `equals()`, however in reality I have no idea how to do it. I have a following class:

```
public class Dog {

   private Integer id;
   private Integer age;
   private Instant dateOfBirth;
}
```

And now, I would like to be able to check if some list of dogs is subset of another list of dogs.

```
ArrayList<Dog>
```

Two dogs I consider as equals when they have the same `age`, `id`, `dateOfBirth`

Ofcourse, it seems to be easy to implement equals:

```
public boolean equals(Dog dog) {
  return (dog.id == this.id && dog.age == dog.age && &this.dateOfBirth.equals(dog.dateOfBirth));
}
```

However, I have no idea how to implement `hashCode` to maintain equals-hashcode contract ?

Comment: isn't ID sufficient? As in if ID is unique and immutable for each dog, you don't need age and dateOfBirth (here one depends on another anyway, so use Instant as higher fidelity, if ID is not sufficient)

Comment: @Tom.Reunick In your equals method you use `==` to compare `Integer` instances. This will only work for values that are part of the integer cache (-128 to 127).

Comment: Side note: Unless you want to accept `null`, use `int` instead of `Integer`. And if null is acceptable `this.dateOfBirth.equals` might crash with an NPE. Also not sure if `==` works properly for `Integer`.

Comment: Interesting that `hashCode` would be used when determining if a list is a sublist of another one. How does that work? Do you have any reference for this algorithm?